# How to force Varnish to see newly created files?

Tags: php, apache, varnish

I have a server with setted up Varnish before the Apache. My PHP app is creating new files to create compressed JS and CSS files, but when these files are created, Varnish do not see these files for 3-4 minutes, so the first pageload got 404 error for the files. I know the files exist, as I see them in the filesystem.

How should I fix this problem? Some htaccess cache headers could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can purge the cached 404 on your VCL (with an especial request) [1] or even force 404 errors to be not cached at all:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  # ...
  if (beresp.status == 404) {
    set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    set beresp.http.cache-control = "no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
  }
  # ...
}
```

[1] https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/purging.html